# Laravel Socialite Github OAuth Response 401 Bad Credentials

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I am working on Laravel 7 and for social login I am using Socialite package.
I am following this [article](https://www.codechief.org/article/oauth-login-using-facebook-google-twitter-and-github-with-laravel-socialite-package) for reference and did exactly the same but I am getting
an unauthorized response with a message - "Bad Credentials". I have also tried resetting the secret key.

[This is my Github settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBRge.png)

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from making sure that your `client_id` and `client_secret` are set correctly, you also need to ensure that your `redirect` value in your `config/services.php`:

```php
'github' => [
  'client_id' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'),
  'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'),
  'redirect' => 'http://yourapp.test/login/github/callback'
],
```

Is **identical** to what you set under your Github app:
[image]